# specify PDF page size using pdfkit in node js

Tags: node.js, pdfkit

I read in pdfkit manual that pdf page can be sized using size[width,height].But when i tried the following code its not working

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

var doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.size=[50,50];
doc.end()
```

Answer (score 28):

After exploration i found the following code is working for me to create PDF document of any size with width,height and margins as variables

```
 var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

    var fs = require("fs");
    var doc=new PDFDocument({
        size: [width,height],
        margins : { // by default, all are 72
            top: 10,
           bottom:10,
            left: 10,
          right: 10
        }
})
```

Comment: width and heights are pixels? cm? points?  if points => is this correct:  85mm = 72*3.34646inches= 240.94512 Points??

Comment: @Suisse do you know finally if are px, cm, points, or another? Thanks

Comment: @Suisse this is the size in pts

Answer (score 1):

It works :)

Dimension are in PostScript points
1 cm = 28.3465 pt