# How can I get PDF dimensions in pixels in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf2json

I tried pdf2json:

```
const PDFParser = require("pdf2json");
let pdfParser = new PDFParser();

pdfParser.loadPDF("./30x40.pdf"); // ex: ./abc.pdf

pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
  width = pdfData.formImage.Width; // pdf width
  height = pdfData.formImage.Pages[0].Height; // page height

  console.log(`Height : ${height}`) // logs 70.866
  console.log(`Width : ${width}`) // logs 53.15
});
```

But it gave the dimensions in a unknown units!

The dimensions in pixels will help me include them in the pdf-poppler module that converts a pdf file to an image and it needs the pdf file height in pixels.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702471/specify-pdf-page-size-using-pdfkit-in-node-js

Comment: @Jordan That question is about creating a new empty pdf file of a certain size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [calipers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/calipers).
Code example:

```js
const Calipers = require('calipers')('png', 'pdf');
Calipers.measure('./30x40.pdf')
.then(data => {
  const { width, height } = data.pages[0];
});
```

Alternatively, try a module which converts it without needing width/height:
[pdf2pic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2pic) [pdf-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-image) [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick)
If you're set on using pdf2json, please read [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json#output-format-reference) bit of documentation describing the units of the output.

Comment: pdf2pic can convert pdf to image, but default size is landscape (for all pdf sizes), If we need an larger image with pdf ratio, we need to get the pdf real width + height, then set it into pdf2pic convert options

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party, but as discussed here: [stackoverflow pdf2json unit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510645/17449103)
you can multiply your width and height by **24**
Just like:

```
width = pdfData.formImage.Width * 24; // pdf width
height = pdfData.formImage.Pages[0].Height * 24; // page height
```

and you get Pixel.